# Visual Studio 2010 Saving Projects

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

To All,

I haven't used a Visual Studio in quite a few years, and don't remember what version I had used.  I created 15-20 libraries and 30-40 utilities - all in C.

I recently decided that I wanted to enhance some of the libraries and utilities and acquired Visual Studio 2010.  I open an existing project (.dsw) and I get a popup that says "The project ' must be converted to the current ... Convert and open this project?' I click on Yes.  I then get a popup that says "A file with the same name ... already exists on disk.  Do you want to overwrite the project and its imported sheets?'  Again I say Yes.

I go along my way and make a bunch of changes to the project.  I click on "Save All."  I then close the project and when I reopen, it is like I didn't change anything!  I get the same popups again!

I've check the permissions on the directory and files and they should be writable.  I have SCOURED the net trying to find out what I am doing wrong to no avail.

Any helpful pointers would be greatly appreciated!

TIA,

je

Answer (score 0):

`.dsw` extension was used by Visual Studio 6, [Visual Studio 2010 project files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2(v=vs.100).aspx) have extension `.vcxproj`. The conversion process mentioned in your question creates those new project files. Open them instead of old `.dsw`

Comment: @jmes7827, If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions :)